# Ways to keep a collection ordered in Backbone?

Tags: backbone.js

I have a collection which uses comparator function to sort its models.
The models have a rank-attribute used for sorting them.

In my model view I have a button for upgrading and downgrading the rank attribute by one. By listening to the collections change event I can call "sort" every time the rank attribute of a model is changed, thus reordering the the list.

The problem is keeping the rank unique - now I'm just changing the rank value of a single model, which will not affect the other models.
For example:

1. item A, rank 1
2. item B, rank 2
3. item C, rank 3

To:

1. item A, rank 1
2. item B, rank 1
3. item C, rank 3

Is there a smart (backbone) way of changing the ranks of the rest of the models?

If it needs to be done manually, then what is a good strategy for doing it? I'm currently changing the model from the model's view and listening to change in collection's view so there's is no obvious way to affect the ranks of the adjacent models.

Comment: Confused ;). Do you change the rank or someone using the app will? it seems to be something like upvote/downvote is it? Why do you want to make the ranks unique if you don't have control over them

Comment: The ranks should be unique, because I don't want Item A and Item B both have a rank of 1. The idea is that I have a list of items and they can be "upvoted/downvoted" by the user of the app. But they should always have just one correct ordering, i.e. now two items can share a rank.

Comment: then remove the  comparator. Why do you need one when sorting does not occur. Otherwise do not subscribe to the `reset` event during the sort

Comment: I don't understand how removing the comparator would help? I do want the items to be listed in the order of the rank. Meanwhile I made a server-side solution: When the rank is upvoted or downvoted, the model is saved. The server then does the magic with the list and backbone re-fetches the collection resulting in correctly ordered list.

Comment: In fact, I'm no longer sure if it makes sense to do this in the client-side. After all you can only save individual models and not collections, right?